# Can Process.Start Be Executed concurrently on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, process

This method is defined within an ASP.NET Web application (.NET 4.5.2) that runs on IIS 6 or above:

```
public string GetValueFromProcess()
{
    string val = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(GetMyExeFilePath());
        p.WaitForExit();
        val = mainp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    return val;
}
```

Will such a function be able to execute **concurrently** without problems or will I wrap it with a [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)?

Obviously there are parameters that shall be passed along to the process but I removed that part for simplicity.

Comment: Why do you think it can't be run concurrently?

Comment: Because I'm not sure whether IIS would create a separate instance of the process for every request or it will hang. I'm not familiar with how IIS deals with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will block the current request, waiting for "p.WaitForExit();" to complete. Concurrent requests will spawn multiple processes. You will also need to consider the IIS request script timeout setting which will throw a ThreadAbort exception.